# Tkinter - mainloop and after not working as expected (kanyewest quote training)

Tags: python, tkinter

Super() python newbie here.
I am following an online training where I need to create a tkinter window to get Kanye West quotes and to be refreshed every X seconds.

I get the first refresh due to my window.after() but then it never happens again.

From my understanding, once the code between Tk() and mainloop() is done, it reads it again as part of the loop. So I should get a newquote immediately again and another one with the after, all looped.

I think Im missing a concept on the behavior of the mainloop...

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter, requests
from tkinter import *


def get_quotes():
    kanye = requests.get(url="https://api.kanye.rest")
    if kanye.raise_for_status() is None:
        quote = kanye.json()
        return quote["quote"]


def change_quote(text):
    quote_canvas.itemconfig(TEXT, text=text)


# --- UI design of application ---
window = Tk()
window.title("Kanye quotes API")
window.config(background="white", padx=20, pady=20)

# -- Canvas for quote ---
quote_canvas = Canvas(height=414, width=300, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
quote_img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Kanye REST API/images/background.png")
quote_canvas.create_image(150, 200, image=quote_img)
TEXT = quote_canvas.create_text(150, 180, text=get_quotes(), font=("courier", 20, "normal"),
                                      fill="black", justify=CENTER, width=280)
quote_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

# -- Canvas for emoji ---
emoji_canvas = Canvas(height=150, width=131, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
emoji_img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Kanye REST API/images/kanye.png")
emoji_canvas.create_image(70, 75, image=emoji_img)
emoji_canvas.grid(row=1, column=0)

NEW_TEXT = get_quotes()
window.after(3500, change_quote, NEW_TEXT)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you post the right code?  There are no uses of `.after()` here.

Comment: `after` only schedules a function to run once. You have to reschedule it if you want it to run more than once.

Comment: _"From my understanding, once the code between Tk() and mainloop() is done, it reads it again as part of the loop."_ - no, that's not how mainloop works. Code is only executed once. `mainloop` just looks for events and calls callbacks.

Comment: @jaysonharper  , indeed sorry (long day and tired) I removed a few lines in my pycharm and forgot to put back.

I corrected the code in my initial post

Comment: @BryanOakley
Indeed, It seems I got the concept wrong. so I shall call a simple function instead of after and put the after in the function itself?

Comment: yes, that's a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK

I managed to make this work:

Change the function:

```
def change_quote():
    window.after(5000, change_quote)
    quote_canvas.itemconfig(TEXT, text=get_quotes())
```

And Im simply calling `change_quote()` before the `.mainloop()`.